# Display corruption at system installation

Tags: system-installation, display, nvidia

On my old Compaq Presario F700 (NVidia GeForce 7000/610M C67), display is corrupted from start. That means, resolution isn't a standard VGA one, as other distros allow installation. How could I install Elementary, then ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit to the Q&A model (you say it yourself that you don't expect an answer), so I'll vote for closing. It would probably be best to post this to reddit, for example.

Comment: true; I perhaps was way upset  :-/ I revamp it.

Comment: after hours and hours searching docs, burning a tenth of DVD, trying Debian, Ubuntu, openSuSE, Elementary and Mint, I got it working. And I can answer my own question.

Comment: Kudos for reworking your communication into a constructive tone after overcoming the initial frustration, and for coming back to offer a solution to the community. Not everyone can do that :)

Answer (score 1):

1. on such an old PC with an amd64 CPU *but* with a 32 bits BIOS and a 32 bits NVidia card, stay on a **x86 32 bits installation of Linux**; otherwise, the NVidia-304 driver couldn't work correctly, and you couldn't get any graphical acceleration.
2. At early start of installation, a little **pictogram for accessibility** shows at bottom of the screen; press [return] at this time: a menu shows. Pressing [tab] allows editing of the menu commands; replace "**quiet splash**" with "**nomodeset**", which prevents the installer of choosing the better available resolution (the one who flickered the screen). Validate with [return]. Install will then run in 1024x768, without problem. Beware: in Kernel Options (F6), there is a "nomodeset" option; it doesn't seem to work, and doesn't prevent screen corruption.
3. Once your Linux distribution installed (Elementary as well as any other), install the nvidia-304 legacy (non-free) driver (use Synaptic, or even the software/driver manager, or YasT on SuSE). You should endly get the native 1280x800 resolution, with some graphical acceleration.
4. nota: some distros allow choice of another graphical pilote at install time; it should only work, if the distro isnt' a amd64 one installing on a too old PC with 32 bits internal components (BIOS, cards...). Some distros only provide the grub menu at installation start, reached by pressing (just once!) F9 (if pressed twice, start process resumes!). You can edit the command by pressing "e" and launch it by pressing F10, after replacing of "quiet splash" by "nomodeset".